# java - How can i make this calculation faster?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

My function is `total += Math.sqrt(num) - Math.cbrt(num);` I want to apply this to every number till the max value(starting from 0) i determine. So i wrote some code  below which uses divide technique to calculate faster. How can i fasten this calculation? Code below(*8 threads*) takes **20 seconds** to finish while non-thread takes **150 seconds** to finish. I believe with `forkjoinpool` i can make it faster or maybe `parallel streams`? How to implement it with them?

```
public class Main {

    private static int targetNum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private static int threadCount = 8;
    private static double total = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();


        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);

        try {
            ArrayList<Future<Double>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int a = 0; a < threadCount; a++){
                calculatorService ss = new calculatorService(a*(targetNum/threadCount) ,(a+1) *(targetNum/threadCount));
                futureList.add(executor.submit(ss));
            }
            for(int a = 0; a < threadCount; a++){
                total+= futureList.get(a).get();
            }

            System.out.println("Result= "+ df2.format(total) + "\nTime passed= " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time)/1000f));
            executor.shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
class calculatorService implements Callable<Double>{

    private int start,end;

    public SqrtSummer(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public Double call(){
        double total = 0;
        for (int a = start; a < end; a++) {
            total += Math.sqrt(a) - Math.cbrt(a);
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

`futureList.get(a).get();`i had to do that in that way because i don't know the thread(core) count. Thus i can not write futureList.get(0).get() + futureList.get(1).get()..... I know till futureList.get(0).get() loop will wait but still they will be doing their job. My thread count is not fixed and can change any moment.

Comment: If you have 8 cores, and the sequential time is 150 seconds, the best time you can hope by using the same algorithm and parallelizing it on 8 cores is 150/8 = 18.75 seconds. So 20 seconds is very close, and you won't get much better than that without adding cores or changing the algorithm.

Comment: @JBNizet So you are saying design wise my implementation is ok but i need to find a faster  way for Math.sqrt etc?

Answer (score 3):

MultiThreading can benefit when your application is I/O intensive. However, this application is computing sensitive, maybe assign `threadCount` the number of your processor is best choice:

```
private static int threadCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Main {

    private static int targetNum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private static int threadCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    private static double total = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Future<Double>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
        int lastSize=futureList.size();

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);

        Runnable sumRunnable= () ->
        {   int sumCalculatedTill=0;
            while(!executor.isTerminated())
            {
                if(lastSize!=futureList.size())
                {
                    for(int i=sumCalculatedTill;i<futureList.size();i++)
                        try {
                            total+=futureList.get(i).get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    sumCalculatedTill=futureList.size();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Result= "+ df2.format(total) + "\nTime passed= " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time)/1000f));
        };
        Thread thread=new Thread(sumRunnable);
        thread.start();

        try {


            for(int a = 0; a < threadCount; a++){
                calculatorService ss = new calculatorService(a*(targetNum/threadCount) ,(a+1) *(targetNum/threadCount));
                futureList.add(executor.submit(ss));

            }
            /*for(int a = 0; a < threadCount; a++){
                total+= futureList.get(a).get();
            }
*/

            executor.shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
class calculatorService implements Callable<Double>{

    private int start,end;

    public calculatorService(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public Double call(){
        double total = 0;
        for (int a = start; a < end; a++) {
            total += Math.sqrt(a) - Math.cbrt(a);
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Just a thought. Let's discuss to optimize it more.

Answer (score 0):

How to reduce your calculation to 1 microsecond? Easy.

Your grand total is : sum of the n square roots - sum of the n cubic roots

Math tips :

```
double sumOfSquareRoots = 2D * Math.pow((n + 0.5D), 1.5D) / 3D - 0.22474487139;
```

See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0877.pdf for cubic roots :)

Comment: More precision loss with this method rite? Otherwise no reason to be faster.

Comment: No reason, really? miliions of loop iterations vs less than 10 maths operations ;) The precision depends on the precision of phi. It's Math, no magic.